# Where the /dev/stderr goes? on ECS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have nginx container and it has this settings,

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Aug  2 05:17 access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Aug  2 05:17 error.log -> /dev/stderr
```

`stdout` is supposed to be appeared in log of `ECS Container` log.

However where the `stderr` goes?

Does it also come to log of `ECS Container` log mixed with `access.log`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STDOUT and STDERR will both be sent to the ECS container's logs.